# imagecolortransparent() issue

Tags: php

So I want this result 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fTBc.png

But all I get with every code I tried is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wVoA.png

Anyone can help me please?

My php code:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(480, 320);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($im, $black);
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($new_file));
imagecopymerge($im, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 480, 320, 100);

$png_to_merge = "./images/video_top70.png";
$frame = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($png_to_merge));
imagecopy($im, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, 480, 320);
$img_final = "./images/top.png";
imagepng($im,$img_final);
```

Comment: I removed the `<br>`'s at the end of the lines as I assumed that was an attempt at formatting and not part of the php.

Comment: So, you want just to add a 'watermark' on the original image? You set black as transparent color and it exists on the original background image. Give us links to the original images.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers. The original images are http://i.imgur.com/ViqYFBF.png and http://i.imgur.com/SbMSR6v.png . For the background part, I did it because I couldnt center the car image into the video/play image. In fact, I always lose the bottom part of the video/play image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'watermark' png already has transparency, no need to select a transparent color.
Comment the lines

```
// $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
// imagecolortransparent($im, $black);
```

And, for the future, select as transparent the color you want to be transparent :) For the given image the choice of black is not a wise one - use alpha channel.

Result

[image]

To crop the result

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(480, 320);
$im2 = imagecreatetruecolor(480, 270);

$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('img1.png'));
imagecopymerge($im, $image, 0, 25, 0, 0, 480, 320, 100);


$frame = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('img2.png'));
imagecopy($im, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, 480, 320);

imagecopyresampled($im2, $im, 0, 0, 0, 25, 480, 270, 480, 270);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im2);
imagedestroy($im2);
```

And we get

[image]

Ok, this is what you need, work with alpha channel

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(480, 320);
$c = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $c);

imagecopymerge($im, imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('img1.png')),
                0, 25, 0, 0, 480, 275, 100);
imagecopy($im, imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('img2.png')),
                0, 0, 0, 0, 480, 320);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Result is the same as second image, but 320px in height.

Comment: If I remove the transparency, the background go black!

Comment: @MarkBel Look at the attached image. Your image with car does not has a solid black background color, so you can not remove the background by settings the black as transparent.

Comment: The car picture is 480x270, the video/play one is 480x320. Is there a way to center the car image into the video/play one and keep the extra 25px as transparent? I do it in photoshop since few weeks, but it takes age since I have +/- 1000 images to edit.

Comment: @MarkBel Photoshop has a batch tool to do things like this ) You can choose any color that does not exist on the original image. Or work with alpha channel. Also you can crop the final image in php.

Comment: Yeah but I need to do it everyday so thats why I'm trying to code something. About the result you just did....mmm it will not works. I really need that the image stay at 320px height. At most, I will deal with that black background.

Comment: @MarkBel Just mention everything that you need at the beginning ) I'll make it 320px, not a problem.

Comment: I was still trying many code then I discover your last answer. Its works now! Thanks!!